# jquery remove check box on condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

In a div there are these check boxes(name="val1") and after a certain operation these check boxes are removed

```
<div name="navigation_b">
    <label id="selectall">
        select all 
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectall" />
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="val1" />   
    <input type="checkbox" name="val1" />   
    <input type="checkbox" name="val1" />   
    <input type="checkbox" name="val1" />   
    <input type="checkbox" name="val1" />   
</div>
```

If all the checkboxes(name =val1) are removed then the selectall should not be visible.How to do this using jquery

Comment: How are the checkboxes being removed?  jQuery, other javascript, server side, etc.

Comment: Are they set to be display:none or are they actually removed?

Comment: The checkboxes are removed using jquery .remove()

Answer (score 1):

```
if( $("input:checkbox[name='val1']").length==0)
{
       $("input:checkbox[name='selectall']")
      .hide();
}
```

Source is [here](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/), and [here](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

**Edit**

You could hide the entire label which contains `selectall` -

```
if( $("input:checkbox[name='val1']").length==0)
{
       $("label#selectall")
      .hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check to see if there are any of the checkboxes and if not then remove the label

```
if($('input:checkbox[name="val1"]').length) {
    // do something
}
else {
    // do something else
}
```

the above is untested but i think it's pretty close.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is to auto-show the *select all checkbox*, when the others are removed, I don't think that is possible with jQuery, unless there is an event that jQuery sports which would fire when an element is removed. You'll have to show the *select all checkbox* manually may be by using one of the fine solutions provided in the other answers.